# Swapping between versions of a webservice c#

Tags: c#, web-services, versioning

I wish to maintain code that calls an existing webservice but make it so I can call a newer version of the same webservice (based on a config setting). I'll need to have different namespaces as the webservice is the same name. Does anyone have any best practice patters for accomplishing this?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Do you want to be able to call both web services within an instance of the application, or will it be only one or the other based on the config setting?

Comment: You need to look up the "Factory" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The "Factory" pattern (and probably "Facade" pattern) are your friends here.

So, given you have two services that implement a common method or set of methods you can do this kind of thing to make a general service factory:

I'm assuming you have two services called `ServiceOld` and `ServiceNew` (they could have the same name and sit in different namespaces as is your case). And that these services share a common method `public string GetName();`.

First I create an interface that embodies these services:

```
public interface IService
{
    string GetName();
}
```

Now, if you can modify the service code directly you could implement this interface directly on your services, or you could perhaps inherit down your services and implement this interface. I'm going to assume that your services are both not under your control and are sealed. So I would implement two wrapper (or facade) classes.

```
public class ServiceOldWrapper : IService
{
    private ServiceOld _inner = new ServiceOld();
    public string GetName()
    {
        return _inner.GetName();
    }
}

public class ServiceNewWrapper : IService
{
    private ServiceNew _inner = new ServiceNew();
    public string GetName()
    {
        return _inner.GetName();
    }
}
```

Now I can write the factory class.

```
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public IService CreateService()
    {
        if (configValueThatYouNeedToRead == "Old")
        {
            return new ServiceOldWrapper();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ServiceNewWrapper();
        }
    }
}
```

Now calling this becomes simple:

```
var sf = new ServiceFactory();
var s = sf.CreateService();
var name = s.GetName();
```

You probably will need to handle cleaning up your services a little better than I have so your code will be a bit more complicated, but this should get you started.